# How to sort a list of items by one of its component dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

this is my first question in stackoverflow. Hope I'm clear.

I would like to transform the following list (sorted ascending by the first element of each item):

```
[[7, 4], [9, 4], [10, 1]]
```

into this(sorted descending by the second element of each item, then descending by the first element):

```
[[9, 4], [7, 4], [10, 1]]
```

I have tried the sort attribute with no success.
Any hint?
thks

Comment: What is "the sort attribute"? Is that in a particular programming language?

Comment: I am trying to code this transformation in Python. I would like to perform a descending sort by the second element of each item of the list, then by the first element.

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html ?

Comment: `l = [[7, 4], [9, 4], [10, 1]]` then `l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)` or alternatively `l.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], -x[0]))` or alternatively `from operator import itemgetter; l.sort(key=itemgetter(1,0), reverse=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: yes, I also tried sorted(l,key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True). It worked too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize sorting behavior, you can provide the `key` keyword argument in `sorted()` or `list.sort()`. In OP's case, they `key` argument should be a function that takes in one item in the original list (i.e., a pair of numbers like `[7, 4]`) and then returns the pair of numbers reversed (i.e., `[4, 7]`). We need to reverse the sort because by default, the `sorted()` and `list.sort()` sort in from smallest to largest.

See more about sorting in python, and in particular the `key` functions, at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions.

```py
original = [[7, 4], [9, 4], [10, 1]]
desired = [[9, 4], [7, 4], [10, 1]]

original_sorted = sorted(
    original, 
    key=lambda pair: (pair[1], pair[0]), reverse=True)

original_sorted == desired  # True
```

The `lambda` is a function. It is equivalent to the function below. We use a `lambda` here because it is compact and we do not need to refer to this function anywhere else.

```py
def key_function(pair):
    return pair[1], pair[0]
```